# Vue.$http is undefined, Laravel, not using npm

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I'm tryin to work with Vue directives, and keep encountering the *Vue.http is not defined* error.

I have this snippet in my main.js file,

```
Vue.directive('ajax', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener(
            'submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                let button = el.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
                let resetForm = true;
                let formData = new FormData(el);

                let formInstance = el;
                let method = el.method.toLowerCase();

                formInstance.classList.add('loading');
                console.log(Vue.$http);
                Vue.$http[method](el.action, formData).then(response => {
                    // success callback
                }, response => {
                    // error callback
                });
            }
        );
    }
});
```

and in body i just load js files like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.resource.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}?v={{ time() }}"></script>
```

However I keep encountering that Vue.http is undefined :/ I'm not using npm, since I have no clue how to setup all the packages... Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `Vue.http` not `Vue.$http`.

Comment: Apparently, you are correct. I was trying this before, however only now it started working. Thank you.